# MYSQL: using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE + COALESCE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have written below stored procedure which inserts records for particular date. If the date is duplicate then should update the values. But while inserting a new record for same date, if any of the value is null, it is making already inserted values for that date null as well.
My Stored Procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_setrecords (IN daten date,IN daystart time,IN lunchstart time,IN lunchend time,IN breakstart time,IN breakend time,IN dayend time,IN casualleave time,IN sickleave time,IN holidays time,IN leavewithoutpay time)
    BEGIN
        insert into dailyrecord (date,daystart,lunchstart,lunchend,breakstart,breakend,dayend,casualleave,sickleave,holidays,leavewithoutpay) values              (daten,daystart,lunchstart,lunchend,breakstart,breakend,dayend,casualleave,sickleave,holidays,leavewithoutpay) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        date = COALESCE(VALUES(date)),
        daystart = COALESCE(VALUES(daystart)),
        lunchstart = COALESCE(VALUES(lunchstart)),
        lunchend = COALESCE(VALUES(lunchend)), 
        breakstart = COALESCE(VALUES(breakstart)), 
        breakend = COALESCE(VALUES(breakend)),
        dayend = COALESCE(VALUES(dayend)),
        casualleave = COALESCE(VALUES(casualleave)), 
        sickleave = COALESCE(VALUES(sickleave)), 
        holidays = COALESCE(VALUES(holidays)),
        leavewithoutpay = COALESCE(VALUES(leavewithoutpay));
    END
```

Example: initial values are:
"2018-01-02","9:30:00",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null"

then if i insert 13:30:30 for same date at second position, it returns:

"2018-01-02",null,"13:30:00",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null"

How can I update the value only if it is not null?

Answer (score 0):

Your `COALESCE()`s need additional arguments:

```
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        date = COALESCE(VALUES(date), date),
        daystart = COALESCE(VALUES(daystart), daystart),
        lunchstart = COALESCE(VALUES(lunchstart), lunchstart),
        . . .
```

This will keep the new value first, then the existing value.